# How do I configure ngResource to namespace it's put/post data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have the following service defined to handle my User resource.  The server returns namespaced JSON data, and expects namespaced JSON data in return.  Unfortunately, while I've been able to to configure it to read the data, it refuses to namespace the output data.  The closest I've come is with the `writeUserKey` function, and that just causes the server to complain.  I think it's overriding the JSON encoding, causing angular to emit just `[object object]` instead of a JSON string.  How do I get this to work?

Code:

```
servicesModule.factory('User', ['$resource', '$q', 'API_BASE',
  function($resource, $q, apiPath){
    var readUsersKey = function(data, headersGetter){
      if(data.users) return data.users;
      return data;
    };
    var writeUserKey = function(data, headersGetter){
      data = { user: data};
      return data;
    };
    var readUserKey = function(data, headersGetter){
      if (data.user) return data.user;
      return data;
    };
    return $resource(apiPath+'users/:id', {id:'@_id'},{
        index:   { method: 'get', isArray:true, responseType: 'json', transformResponse:readUsersKey},
        show:    { method: 'get', responseType: 'json', transformResponse:readUserKey},
        update:  { method: 'put', responseType: 'json', transformResponse:readUserKey, 
          transformRequest:writeUserKey},
        create:  { method: 'post', responseType: 'json', transformResponse:readUserKey, 
          transformRequest:writeUserKey}
      });
  }]);
```

Original output: `{ "key":"value","key2":"value2","key2":"value2" }`

Current Output: `[object object]`

Desired Output: `{ "user": { "key":"value","key2":"value2","key2":"value2" } }`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes lunch helps.  After grabbing some food and puttering around on other parts of hte project, I realized the solution was insanely obvious.  If I'm overriding the default serialization, I just need to reproduce a simple .toJson() call.

Change writeUserKey to:

```
var writeUserKey = function(data, headersGetter){
  return angular.toJson({ user: data});
};
```

Still seems like this is way more complex than something that should be easily done out-of-the-box should require, but it works.  If there's a better approach to handling namespaced data, please let me know!